# Self Referential Relationship ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

To make a self referential relationship in active record, I have followed the self-referential model shown in rails-cast #163 http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association, but I don't like this model because I then have to write friendship **and** inverse_friendships, couldn't I just do something like:

in my person.rb

```
class Person 
  has_many :friendships
  has_many :friendships, :foreign_key => "friend_id"
  has_many :friends, :through => :friendships
  has_many :friends, :through => :friendships, :source => :person
end
```

and in my friendship.rb

```
class Friendship
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "Person"
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't have similarly named associations, these names need to be unique within the model.  Otherwise, how will ActiveRecord know which `friendships` you mean when you have `@user.friendships` in your code?

Comment: Isn't this answer from @apneadiving useful for this question? http://stackoverflow.com/a/4727419/976775

Comment: Hahaha ya, I was confusing my project with the example. will edit. +1